# Memcpy integer to buffer

Tags: c

So I have the following:

```
char * buffer = (char *) malloc(2*80 + 4);
uint32_t networkedRin = htonl(student->rin);

printf("RIN %u\n", student->rin);

//Clear all memory and copy the first last and rin into the new buffer
memset(buffer, '\0', 164);
memcpy(buffer, student->firstname, 80);
memcpy(buffer+80, student->lastname, 80);
memcpy(buffer+160, &networkedRin, 4);

printf("Networked rin: %u\n", networkedRin);

printf("L5: %s %s %u\n", buffer, buffer+80, buffer+160);
```

and I am very confused because when I do the printing at the end the expected value is the same as Networked rin value printed earlier but it is not, in fact its garbage because it is constantly changing with every run. Now I know I should be using sizeof or whatever but we were told to just use the hard coded value of 4 for uint32 and what not. I'm stuck as to why I'm getting garbage when trying to display the networked rin number from the buffer.

For example I am receiving this output after two runs of the program

```
RIN 60
Networked rin: 1006632960
L5: loller cats 16375984


RIN 60
Networked rin: 1006632960
L5: loller cats 10260656
```

I'm sure its something simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: Well being as how this is all C I can't I don't really know why I tagged with c++ I guess just habit of working on C++ projects I did but yes no new here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buffer+160` is not the value you are looking for.
`buffer+160` is a a ***pointer*** to your `int`, not your `int` itself.

You must type-cast and de-reference the pointer to see the value you want.

```
printf("L5: %s %s %u\n", buffer, buffer+80, *(uint32_t*)(buffer+160));
```

Comment: Thank you I feel stupid for missing that now but I'm in a time crunch

Comment: In general, there's no guarantee that you can just cast a pointer from `char` to `uint32_t` and end up with a valid pointer (due to alignment).  It happens that in this case it will work out because of the alignments involved, but in general one should use `memcpy` instead of casting and dereferencing.

Comment: Yes I realize this. The prints are really just debugging for me and won't be in the final product so it didn't wind up mattering

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("L5: %s %s %u\n", buffer, buffer+80, buffer+160);
```

`buffer+160` is a pointer to `char`, so your are printing an *address*.